# How to know the pressed button while opening AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android

i have this:

```
  public void showDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(updatedActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose the currency you would like to exchange.");

    //list of items
    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

    String positiveText = getString(android.R.string.ok);
    builder.setPositiveButton(positiveText,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //So here i wanna a code like : If pressbutton = buttonto, then buttonto.setText(selecteditem..)
                }
            });


    String negativeText = getString(android.R.string.cancel);
    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeText,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // negative button logic
                }
            });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    // display dialog
    dialog.show();
}
```

In the on click event, i wanna know which the button was pressed, so for example if buttonto.ispressed then buttonto.settext(the selected item)

So how to do it
Thanks

Comment: So?? Any help??

Comment: what is buttonto.ispressed?

Comment: No, it isn't a real code, i was just letting you know how i want.

Comment: And what do you want? you want something to do when you click on PositiveButton? AlertDialog has only one Positive Button.